# Is it safe to exclude Scaffolding packages from publish version?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget, scaffolding

I have [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design/) in a project.

Can it be safely excluded from publishing (`<ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>`)?

Is there scenario, when during runtime, code has dependency on this package?

As I understand this package is used only for generating the code during development.

I don't see any reason to add its dll in published code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it safe to exclude Scaffolding packages from publish version?

As [the package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design/) describes,

> Code Generation tool for ASP.NET Core. Contains the
> dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator command used for generating controllers
> and views.

It only works for generating code for views or controllers during developing and the project itself does not depend on the package at runtime.

**So it is safe to exclude that nuget package from publishing using your method.** And you do not have to worry too much about it.